# Is it possible to make multi-edit in table's column - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table with data. I have ONE EDITABLE column, now I can send one changed object per query. My question: is it possible somehow to send a few changed objects after editing in one query, if yes then how?

Comment: After I would like to send this array of objects to a controller(asp.net)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is the place where the developers help each other. We all ready to help but you should try at least something and show some piece of code here.. so that we can have a better idea :)